# Line With Two Origins Quotient

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am a bit confused with the following wording in the "line with two origins" problem (from Lee's Smooth Manifolds):

> Let X be the set of points $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $y = \pm 1$, and let $M$ be the quotient of $X$ by the equivalence relation generated by $(x,-1)\sim (x, 1)$ for all $x \neq 0$.

In particular, if $q: (x, y) \to \{(x, 1), (x, -1)\}, y=\pm 1, x \neq 0$ is the quotient map, I thought a set $G \subset M$ was open if and only if $q^{-1}(G)\subset X$ were open. Is $X$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Clarification with regard to the quotient map definition would be much appreciated.

Comment: Editing a question after a good answer is not only unnecessary, but it is a particularly bad idea when the edits obscure important points that are addressed in the answer, thus invalidating portions of the answer and confusing future readers who come to this post to understand the topic. I suggest that you should simply roll back those edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points, one of which might clear it up for you:

- Your definition of the quotient map is almost correct, but the condition is that $g^{-1}(G)$ should be open in $X$, not in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The set $X$ is to be regarded as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the subspace topology.
- $X$ is then homeomorphic to the disjoint union of two real lines.
- The line with two origins is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as you seem to say (but I may have misunderstood you there). If you consider an open interval of the line with two origins which doesn't contain either origin, then such an open interval will be homeomorphic to an open interval on the real line.

Edit: and as Thomas points out, your definition of the quotient map is valid for $x\neq 0$ but not at zero.

Comment: Thank you. As a follow up: is an element of the quotient space a set consisting of two points?

Comment: @LukeTux for all points except the origin, yes. For $x=0$ we get two seperate classes $\{ (0,1) \}$ and $\{ (0,-1) \}$.